# Pricing data checker script

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, csv

I was recently given a task to implement a data-checker script which given an input file containing (date, last_price) values should check for 3 different kind of errors - missing values, stale values and outliers and returns list of errors. 
I wrote the code below and the feedback I got was that it was not "pythonic" enough. Can someone please let me know how I can make this more pythonic? What parts look good, what don't? Will be extremely helpful as I write more python code in future.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys
import csv
import pprint
import statistics
from datetime import date

class DataChecker:
    class DatePrice:
        def __init__(self, input_date, price):
            try:
                day, month, year = input_date.split("/")
                self._price_date = date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
            except ValueError:
                # Don't tolerate invalid date
                raise

            try:
                self._price = float(price)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                self._price = 0

        @property
        def date(self):
            return self._price_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

        @property
        def date_obj(self):
            return self._price_date

        @property
        def price(self):
            return self._price

        def __repr__(self):
            return f"{self.date}, {self.price}"

    def __init__(self, input_date_price_values):
        self._date_price_values = []
        for date, price in input_date_price_values:
            try:
                self._date_price_values.append(self.DatePrice(date, price))
            except ValueError:
                pass

        self._date_price_values.sort(key=lambda x: x.date_obj)

        self._stale_price_dict = {}

        self._outlier_low, self._outlier_high = self._calculate_outlier_thresholds_using_iqr(
            self._date_price_values
        )

    def check_for_errors(self):
        """
        returns -> List[tuple(date, float, error)]

        errors = 'missing value', 'stale value' or 'outlier'

        Uses 3 different error checkers to check for errors in data
        1. Checks for missing values in data -> categorises missing values as any value == 0, or empty string or nulls
        2. Checks for stale values in data -> categorises stale values as any value that remains unchanged 
            for 5 business days. For stale values it returns the last date on which it was repeated
        3. Checks for outlier values in data -> Uses Interquartile range (IQR) and a low threshold of 
            first-quartile-value - 1.2 x IQR and high-threshold of third-quartile-value + 1.2 x IQR. 
            Any values outside this range are deemed as outliers
        """
        errors = []
        for datePrice in self._date_price_values:
            if self._is_value_missing(datePrice.price):
                self._add_to_errors(datePrice, "missing value", errors)
            elif self._is_value_stale(datePrice.price):
                self._add_to_errors(datePrice, "stale value", errors)
            elif self._is_value_outlier(datePrice.price):
                self._add_to_errors(datePrice, "outlier", errors)
            else:
                continue

        return errors

    def _add_to_errors(self, datePrice, error_string, errors):
        error_tuple = (datePrice.date, datePrice.price, error_string)
        errors.append(error_tuple)

    def _is_value_missing(self, price):
        if price is None or price == 0:
            return True
        return False

    def _is_value_stale(self, price):
        if price in self._stale_price_dict:
            self._stale_price_dict[price] += 1
            if self._stale_price_dict[price] >= 5:  # 5 business days in week
                return True
        else:
            self._stale_price_dict.clear()
            self._stale_price_dict[price] = 1
        return False

    def _is_value_outlier(self, price):
        if price < self._outlier_low or price > self._outlier_high:
            return True
        return False

    def _calculate_outlier_thresholds_using_iqr(self, data_price_values):
        price_values = sorted([dataPrice.price for dataPrice in data_price_values])

        median_index = len(price_values) // 2
        first_quartile = statistics.median(price_values[:median_index])
        third_quartile = statistics.median(price_values[median_index + 1 :])

        iqr = third_quartile - first_quartile

        low_iqr = first_quartile - 1.2 * iqr
        high_iqr = third_quartile + 1.2 * iqr

        return low_iqr, high_iqr

    def _calculate_outlier_thresholds_using_mean_deviation(self, data_price_values):
        price_values = sorted([dataPrice.price for dataPrice in data_price_values])

        mean_value = statistics.mean(price_values)
        std_dev = statistics.stdev(price_values)

        low_iqr = mean_value - 2 * std_dev
        high_iqr = mean_value + 2 * std_dev

        return low_iqr, high_iqr


def check_file_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as data_file:
        raw_data = csv.DictReader(data_file)
        input_data = []
        for row in raw_data:
            input_data.append((row["Date"], row["Last Price"]))

        data_checker = DataChecker(input_data)
        errors = data_checker.check_for_errors()

        pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
        pp.pprint(errors)
        print(f"Total Errors Found: {len(errors)}")

        return errors


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Please provide filepath")
        sys.exit()

    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    check_file_data(file_path)
```

To test put the above code in a file called "data_checker.py" and test code below in a file called "test_data_checker.py" in the same directory and run:

> python3.6 -m pytest -v test_data_checker.py

```
import pytest

from data_checker import DataChecker

test_data = [
    (
        pytest.param(
            [("01/02/2010", "10"), ("02/02/2010", "10.09"), ("03/02/2010", "10.12")],
            [],
            id="no-errors-in-data",
        )
    ),
    (
        pytest.param(
            [("01/02/2010", "0.0"), ("02/02/2010", ""), ("03/02/2010", "10.12")],
            [("01/02/2010", 0, "missing value"), ("02/02/2010", 0, "missing value")],
            id="2-zero-values",
        )
    ),
    (
        pytest.param(
            [
                ("01/02/2010", "2"),
                ("02/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("03/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("04/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("05/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("06/02/2010", "1.11"),
            ],
            [],
            id="4-repeated-values-no-stale",
        )
    ),
    (
        pytest.param(
            [
                ("01/02/2010", "1.10"),
                ("02/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("03/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("04/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("05/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("06/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("07/02/2010", "1.11"),
            ],
            [("06/02/2010", 1.12, "stale value")],
            id="1-stale-value",
        )
    ),
    (
        pytest.param(
            [
                ("01/02/2010", "0"),
                ("02/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("03/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("04/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("05/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("06/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("07/02/2010", "1.11"),
            ],
            [("01/02/2010", 0, "missing value"), ("06/02/2010", 1.12, "stale value")],
            id="1-missing-1-stale-value",
        )
    ),
    (
        pytest.param(
            [
                ("01/02/2010", "1.11"),
                ("02/02/2010", "5"),
                ("03/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("04/02/2010", "1.11"),
                ("05/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("06/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("07/02/2010", "1.11"),
            ],
            [("02/02/2010", 5, "outlier")],
            id="1-outlier-value",
        )
    ),
    (
        pytest.param(
            [
                ("01/02/2010", "0"),
                ("02/02/2010", "5"),
                ("03/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("04/02/2010", "1.11"),
                ("05/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("06/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("07/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("08/02/2010", "1.12"),
                ("09/02/2010", "1.12"),
            ],
            [
                ("01/02/2010", 0, "missing value"),
                ("02/02/2010", 5, "outlier"),
                ("09/02/2010", 1.12, "stale value"),
            ],
            id="missing-stale-outlier-value",
        )
    ),
]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_data, expected_value", test_data)
def test_check_for_error(input_data, expected_value):
    data_checker = DataChecker(input_data)
    errors = data_checker.check_for_errors()
    assert errors == expected_value
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You can help reviewers if you provide a short example input for the code so that it can be actually tested. Apart from that, great question. Also at first glance your code looks very good compared to many things I usually see.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AlexV .  I added the tests that I wrote for this script so someone can run it